# Как подгрузить .dll файлы к .exe?

Tags: c#

Как подгрузить `.dll` файлы из другой папки?

Файл `.exe` рядом с .`dll` работает корректно. Но если переместить `.exe` файл в любое другое место, то `.exe` не находит эти `.dll`.

Вопрос: Как задать папку откуда будут браться эти `.dll` ?

Без конфига (файла проекта)!

Comment: а как подгрузить dll, который рядом с exe?

Comment: Полагаю, вам нужно [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/specify-assembly-location)

Comment: А мне кажется тут смело можно закрывать дубликатом на [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/918489/220553) или [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879417/220553). А автору может будет полезно и вовсе запаковать все в .exe, об этом [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471236/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Запаковать нет, не стремлюсь к этому. Нужно именно подгружать из папки

Comment: @InvertSOD Две ссылки выше про это и идут.

Comment: @Grundy, dll которые лежат рядом с .exe просто взаимодействуют они как-то сами подгружаются. Вот я хочу понять как можно сделать из другой папки.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Мне нужно без конфига.

Comment: @InvertSOD Ну так наверно это все надо указывать в вопросе, верно? А то мы сейчас вытягиваем из вас клешнями информацию....

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Извиняюсь, добавил.

Comment: @alexander barakin, Вы читайте что я написал, без конфига!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если без конфига, то только так:

```
using System.Reflection;

//...

private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
     string newdir = "c:\\MyDirectory";        
     string path = Path.Combine(newdir, args.Name);

     if (!path.EndsWith(".dll"))
     {
         path = path + ".dll";
     }

     Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
     return ass;      
}

//...

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
```

Comment: А как можно проверить загрузились ли библиотеки или нет?!

Comment: @InvertSOD если не загрузились, будет исключение при первом обращении к классу из этой библиотеки

Comment: как тогда в таком случае решать проблему?

Comment: @InvertSOD Отлаживать. Для начала убедиться, что обработчик события вообще запускается, что Assembly.LoadFile не возвращает null и т.п. Я надеюсь, строку `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;` вы поместили в коде до того, как библиотека используется?

Comment: + это решение для загрузки только управляемых DLL. Для неуправляемых, решение будет другим.

Comment: А для неправляемых что требуется? Вообще у меня подгрузка от net и native.

Comment: @InvertSOD для неуправляемых все проще: [SetDllDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw)

Comment: А как освобождать .dll файлы через Assembly и SetDllDirectory ?

Comment: @InvertSOD Никак. Управляемые сборки выгружаются только выгрузкой всего домена приложений. Неуправляемые dll можно выгрузить с помощью FreeLibrary, но это нужно делать только для тех, которые вы явно загружаете через LoadLibrary.

Answer (score 3):

Дополню вопрос касательно нативных DLL на основании этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452951/how-to-dynamically-load-and-unload-a-native-dll-file):

Нужно через P/Invoke описать 2 функции:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libname);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

//Load
IntPtr Handle = LoadLibrary(fileName);
if (Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
     int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
     throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to load library (ErrorCode: {0})",errorCode));
}

//Free
if(Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        FreeLibrary(Handle);
```

Если мы хотим работать с функцией из загруженной либы(а мы это хотим, иначе не грузили бы), то нужно еще определить `GetProcAddress`

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName); 


    IntPtr funcaddr = GetProcAddress(Handle,functionName);
```

И потом создать делегат

```
YourFunctionDelegate function = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcaddr,typeof(YourFunctionDelegate )) as YourFunctionDelegate ;
function.Invoke(pass here your parameters);
```

Помните, что C# не поддерживает работу с неуправляемыми объектами=> возможны только API вызовы. Если нужно создавать неуправляемые объекты, то нужно делать прослойку на `C++/CLI`

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете подгружать DLL через рефлексию непосредственно в рантайме:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\DLL.dll");

        foreach(Type type in DLL.GetExportedTypes())
        {
            var c = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            type.InvokeMember("Output", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, c, new object[] {@"Hello"});
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Источник: [тут.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362368/loading-dlls-at-runtime-in-c-sharp)