# Складывать зависимости в отдельную папку при компиляции

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Можно ли в Visual Studio 2019 при сборке проекта складывать зависимости(dll) в отдельную папку?

А то при сборке standalone под .NET CORE большое кол-во dll падают в папку с exe-ком.

Это как-то можно исправить?

Знаю, что в конфигах можно подшаманить и указать директории для поиска, но это нужно:

1. Держать конфиг в актуальном состоянии
2. Настроить постбилд эвенты для перекладывания сборок...

P.S ~такой же вопрос я задавал когда-то давно, но с того момента прошло столько времени+ вышел Net Core.

Comment: Либо перейти на Net Core 3.0 и собирать проект в один файл.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Сборка в 1 файл не есть гуд, имхо. Так как теряется возможность точечного обновления приложения, когда нужно подменить одну ддлку.

Comment: Ну, а какая тогда разница куда дллки складывать?

Comment: @ГеннадийП Организовать некоторую иерархию например.